# Collection removeAll ignoring case?

Tags: java, collections, case-insensitive, hashset

Ok so here is my issue. I have to `HashSet`'s, I use the `removeAll` method to delete values that exist in one set from the other.

Prior to calling the method, I obviously add the values to the `Set`s. I call `.toUpperCase()` on each `String` before adding because the values are of different cases in both lists. There is no rhyme or reason to the case.

Once I call `removeAll`, I need to have the original cases back for the values that are left in the `Set`. Is there an efficient way of doing this without running through the original list and using `CompareToIgnoreCase`?

Example:

List1:

```
"BOB"
"Joe"
"john"
"MARK"
"dave"
"Bill"
```

List2:

```
"JOE"
"MARK"
"DAVE"
```

After this, create a separate `HashSet` for each List using `toUpperCase()` on `String`s. Then call `removeAll`.

```
Set1.removeAll(set2);

Set1:
    "BOB"
    "JOHN"
    "BILL"
```

I need to get the list to look like this again:

```
"BOB"
"john"
"Bill"
```

Any ideas would be much appreciated. I know it is poor, there should be a standard for the original list but that is not for me to decide.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In my original answer, I unthinkingly suggested using a `Comparator`, but this causes the `TreeSet` to violate the [`equals` contract](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) and is a bug waiting to happen:

```
// Don't do this:
Set<String> setA = new TreeSet<String>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
setA.add("hello");
setA.add("Hello");
System.out.println(setA);

Set<String> setB = new HashSet<String>();
setB.add("HELLO");
// Bad code; violates symmetry requirement
System.out.println(setB.equals(setA) == setA.equals(setB));
```

---

It is better to use a dedicated type:

```
public final class CaselessString {
  private final String string;
  private final String normalized;

  private CaselessString(String string, Locale locale) {
    this.string = string;
    normalized = string.toUpperCase(locale);
  }

  @Override public String toString() { return string; }

  @Override public int hashCode() { return normalized.hashCode(); }

  @Override public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof CaselessString) {
      return ((CaselessString) obj).normalized.equals(normalized);
    }
    return false;
  }

  public static CaselessString as(String s, Locale locale) {
    return new CaselessString(s, locale);
  }

  public static CaselessString as(String s) {
    return as(s, Locale.ENGLISH);
  }

  // TODO: probably best to implement CharSequence for convenience
}
```

This code is less likely to cause bugs:

```
Set<CaselessString> set1 = new HashSet<CaselessString>();
set1.add(CaselessString.as("Hello"));
set1.add(CaselessString.as("HELLO"));

Set<CaselessString> set2 = new HashSet<CaselessString>();
set2.add(CaselessString.as("hello"));

System.out.println("1: " + set1);
System.out.println("2: " + set2);
System.out.println("equals: " + set1.equals(set2));
```

This is, unfortunately, more verbose.

Comment: No need to roll your own Comparator. The String class provides one for you: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER

Comment: @bankollity. Thanks! - that's been there since Java 1.2 and I've never noticed it. Code amended.

Comment: Wow that was extremely simple to implement although the documentation leads you to believe that the comparator is used solely for sorting. TreeSet(Comparator c) : Constructs a new, empty set, sorted according to the specified comparator. http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#TreeSet%28java.util.Comparator%29 . I am glad it worked though, Thank you so much for your response!

Comment: I should perhaps note that String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER should be OK for English-language identifiers, but isn't something you should rely on for non-English comparison.

Comment: I'm not sure what I was thinking when I wrote this answer - this violates the contract of `Set`. I'll have to come back with a better solution.

Comment: +1 for providing another answer which doesn't only do what needs to be done, but is also correct (as in obeys requirements).

Comment: Don't get why this "setB.equals(setA) == setA.equals(setB)" violates symmetry requirement. You're comparing different "types" of `Set`. As a side note, this `CaselessString` is not safe either. `toUppercase()` may intoduce unintended bugs in some languages. Details can be found here https://stackoverflow.com/q/11063102/5636313

Answer (score 4):

It could be done by:

1. Moving the content of your lists into case-insensitive `TreeSet`s,
2. then removing all common `String`s case-insensitively thanks `TreeSet#removeAll(Collection<?> c)`
3. and finally relying on the fact that `ArrayList#retainAll(Collection<?> c)` will iterate over the elements of the list and for each element it will call `contains(Object o)` on the provided collection to know whether the value should be kept or not and here as the collection is case-insensitive, we will keep only the `String`s that match case-insensitively with what we have in the provided `TreeSet` instance.

The corresponding code:

```
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>(
    Arrays.asList("BOB", "Joe", "john", "MARK", "dave", "Bill")
);

List<String> list2 = Arrays.asList("JOE", "MARK", "DAVE");

// Add all values of list1 in a case insensitive collection
Set<String> set1 = new TreeSet<>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
set1.addAll(list1);
// Add all values of list2 in a case insensitive collection
Set<String> set2 = new TreeSet<>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
set2.addAll(list2);
// Remove all common Strings ignoring case
set1.removeAll(set2);
// Keep in list1 only the remaining Strings ignoring case
list1.retainAll(set1);

for (String s : list1) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

**Output:**

```
BOB
john
Bill
```

**NB 1:** It is important to have the content of the second list into a `TreeSet` especially if we don't know the size of it because the behavior of `TreeSet#removeAll(Collection<?> c)` depends on the size of both collections, if the size of the current collection is strictly bigger than the size of the provided collection, then it will call directly `remove(Object o)` on the current collection to remove each element, in this case the provided collection could be a list. But if it is the opposite, it will call `contains(Object o)` on the provided collection to know whether a given element should be removed or not so if it is not an case-insensitive collection, we won't get the expected result.

**NB 2:** The behavior of the method `ArrayList#retainAll(Collection<?> c)` described above is the same as the behavior of the default implementation of the method `retainAll(Collection<?> c)` that we can find in `AbstractCollection` such that this approach will actually work with any collections whose implementation of `retainAll(Collection<?> c)` has the same behavior.

Comment: Very nice. I wonder how the retainAll method know to keep the values although in set1 they are kind of different

Comment: @Muky thx for the feedback, I improved my answer to make it clear, hoping that it will be good enough now

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [hashmap](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) and use the capital set as keys that map to the mixed case set.

Keys of hashmaps are unique and you can get a set of them using HashMap.keyset();

to retrieve the original case, it's as simple as HashMap.get("UPPERCASENAME").

And according to the [documentation](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#keySet()):

> Returns a set view of the keys
>   contained in this map. **The set is
>   backed by the map, so changes to the
>   map are reflected in the set, and
>   vice-versa.** The set supports element
>   removal, which removes the
>   corresponding mapping from this map,
>   via the Iterator.remove, Set.remove,
>   removeAll, retainAll, and clear
>   operations. It does not support the
>   add or addAll operations.

So HashMap.keyset().removeAll will effect the hashmap :)

EDIT: use McDowell's solution. I overlooked the fact that you didn't actually need the letters to be upper case :P

Answer (score 1):

This would be an interesting one to solve using [google-collections](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/). You could have a constant Predicate like so:

```
private static final Function<String, String> TO_UPPER = new Function<String, String>() {
    public String apply(String input) {
       return input.toUpperCase();
}
```

and then what you're after could be done someting like this:

```
Collection<String> toRemove = Collections2.transform(list2, TO_UPPER);

Set<String> kept = Sets.filter(list1, new Predicate<String>() {
    public boolean apply(String input) {
        return !toRemove.contains(input.toUpperCase());
    }
}
```

That is:

- Build an upper-case-only version of the 'to discard' list
- Apply a filter to the original list, retaining *only* those items whose uppercased value is *not* in the upper-case-only list.

Note that the output of `Collections2.transform` isn't an efficient `Set` implementation, so if you're dealing with a lot of data and the cost of probing that list will hurt you, you can instead use

```
Set<String> toRemove = Sets.newHashSet(Collections2.transform(list2, TO_UPPER));
```

which will restore an efficient lookup, returning the filtering to O(n) instead of O(n^2).

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know, hashset's use the object's hashCode-method to distinct them from each other.
you should therefore override this method in your object in order to distinct cases.

if you're really using string, you cannot override this method as you cannot extend the String-class.

therefore you need to create your own class containing a string as attribute which you fill with your content. you might want to have a getValue() and setValue(String) method in order to modify the string.

then you can add your own class to the hashmap.

this should solve your problem.

regards